# react-native init Awesomeproject "npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator." windows 10

Tags: android, node.js, windows, react-native

I am trying to follow the instructions for ["Getting started with react-native"](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content).

I know that using windows for my development platform is experimental but this is what I am doing.  I start a "Node.js command prompt" then do ...

```
> npm install -g react-native-cli
> react-native init AwesomeProject
```

... but I get this error ...

```
C:\Users\plankton>react-native init AwesomeProject
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in C:\Users\plankton\AwesomeProject
Installing react-native package from npm...

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install C:\Users\plankton\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\plankton\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  bufferutil.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.c
     Creating library C:\Users\plankton\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\Release\bufferutil.lib and object C:\Users\plankton\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\Release\bufferutil.exp
  Generating code
  Finished generating code
  bufferutil.vcxproj -> C:\Users\plankton\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\Release\\bufferutil.node

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install C:\Users\plankton\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\plankton\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  validation.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.c
     Creating library C:\Users\plankton\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\Release\validation.lib and object C:\Users\plankton\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\Release\validation.exp
  Generating code
  Finished generating code
  validation.vcxproj -> C:\Users\plankton\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\Release\\validation.node

> spawn-sync@1.0.13 postinstall C:\Users\plankton\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\yeoman-generator\node_modules\cross-spawn\node_modules\spawn-sync
> node postinstall


npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.6
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "react-native"
npm ERR! node v4.2.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! path C:\Users\plankton\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\brace-expansion\1.1.2\package\package.json.9d769f6c66df6b0ff357401140ec21e2
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\plankton\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\brace-expansion\1.1.2\package\package.json.9d769f6c66df6b0ff357401140ec21e2' -> 'C:\Users\plankton\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\brace-expansion\1.1.2\package\package.json'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\plankton\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\brace-expansion\1.1.2\package\package.json.9d769f6c66df6b0ff357401140ec21e2' -> 'C:\Users\plankton\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\brace-expansion\1.1.2\package\package.json']
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\plankton\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\brace-expansion\\1.1.2\\package\\package.json.9d769f6c66df6b0ff357401140ec21e2',
npm ERR!   dest: 'C:\\Users\\plankton\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\brace-expansion\\1.1.2\\package\\package.json',
npm ERR!   parent: 'minimatch' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\plankton\AwesomeProject\npm-debug.log

`npm install --save react-native` failed
```

The error output suggest: `Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.`, but how do I do that on a Windows 10 system?

UPDATE: Thank Louy your answer works. Here's a screen shot of what I ended up doing ...

[image: Right click the Node.js command promt and select Run as Adminstrator]

Right click the `Node.js command promtpt` and select `Run as Administrator`.

UPDATE II:  On subsequent iterations I got the same error.  I what I had to do then was what Louy said to do in the comment:

delete the folder `"C:\\Users\\plankton\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache`

UPDATE III:

I had run my Node.js command prompt as Administrator and I had deleted the folder `"C:\\Users\\plankton\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache` and yet I still got the `running this command again as root/Administrator` error. I had to use Windows Explorer to unset the `Read only` and `hidden` properties off the "C:\Users\plankton\AppData` folder.

[image]

Comment: It can be that you've installed something previously as an admin. Did you try deleting the folder "C:\\Users\\plankton\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start up your command line interpreter as an administrator.

- Open start menu
- Type "cmd"
- Right click and choose "Run as Administrator"

Then do the same as you did earlier.

Comment: Thanks! That did it.  I will add a screen shot to my answer showing what you suggested looks like.